# import { takeCoverage } from 'v8'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, vitest, create-vue

Just created a local project using `npm init vue@3` using the option vitest. After installing the packages when executing cmd `yarn test:unit` it throws following errors:

```
$ yarn test:unit
yarn run v1.22.11
warning package.json: No license field
$ vitest --environment jsdom
(node:19544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: file:///D:/create-vue-3/vue-project/node_modules/vitest/dist/create-a1bc541a.js:13
import { takeCoverage } from 'v8';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'v8' does not provide an export named 'takeCoverage'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:121:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:166:5)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Done in 0.25s.
```

see demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-e8wbit?file=vitest.config.ts

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (on macOS, Node 17).

Comment: Also not reproducible on Windows 11, Node 16. What other setup prompts did you pick besides Vitest?

Comment: see demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-e8wbit?file=vitest.config.ts

Comment: If you reinstall `happy-dom` (`npm i happy-dom`), your demo [works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-3lnzag). How did you scaffold that project? That's not from `npm init vue@3` that you mentioned.

Comment: the stackblitz version is from vitest/examples.

Comment: Interesting. Just tried [Vitest's playground link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/github/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/examples/vue), and still don't see the issue. I didn't have to reinstall `happy-dom`. It just worked.